# Expo MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync() does not return any assets

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using a react-native app using expo (I ran `expo prebuild`). I'm trying to use `MediaLibrary` to get the files in the `Recordings/Call` folder. This is my code:

```
  const getFiles = async () => {
    const res = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync("Call");
    console.log(res);
    const assets = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
      album: res,
      mediaType: "audio",
    });
    console.log(assets);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getFiles();
  }, [isVisible]);
```

`res` prints this:

```
{"assetCount": 2, "id": "-1762193519", "title": "Call"}
```

But, when I try to get the assets themselves from `getAssetsAsync`, I get:

```
{"assets": [], "endCursor": "0", "hasNextPage": false, "totalCount": 0}
```

The app also has the permissions needed (`MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync()`). What seems to be wrong? I'm using SDK 50.

Expected the assets to have the asset information, didn't work. Tried `expo prebuild --clean` and then running with `expo run:android --no-build-cache` didn't fix it either.